# try-with-resource vs finally precedence

Tags: java, try-with-resources

What are the precedence rules for `try-with-resource` construct? Here is an example (note: all the mentioned classes implement `Closeable`):

```
try (Page closeablePage = page;
     PipedOutputStream out = outs;
     SequenceWriter sequenceWriter = mapper.writer().writeValuesAsArray(out)) {
  // do stuff
} finally {
  callback.run();
}
```

When is the callback run? My assumptions is:

1. closing the `SequenceWriter`
2. closing the `PipedOutputStream`
3. closing the `Page`
4. running the callback

Am I wrong here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `finally` block will be run after all resources have been closed by the  `try-with-resources` statement.

This is specified in the JLS [section 14.20.3.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.3.2), quoting:

> Furthermore, all resources will have been closed (or attempted to be closed) by the time the finally block is executed, in keeping with the intent of the finally keyword.

Additionally, all resources are closed in reverse declaration order. Quoting [section 14.20.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.3) (emphasis mine):

> **Resources are closed in the reverse order from that in which they were initialized**. A resource is closed only if it initialized to a non-null value. An exception from the closing of one resource does not prevent the closing of other resources. Such an exception is suppressed if an exception was thrown previously by an initializer, the try block, or the closing of a resource.

This means your assumption is correct.

Comment: if an exception occurs then how does it handle

Comment: @war_Hero If there is an exception, all other resources will still be closed and the finally block will still be called (see the second quote of my answer).